# Loading resources in Laravel Valet without trailing slashes

Tags: macos, nginx, laravel-valet

I have a simple html file (trying to start my way with valet) and in it i have a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">`

Thing is, home.test/app doesn't show my styled htm. Chrome's inspector shows it tries to find the resouce file at `home.test/css/main.css`
While in home.test/app/ it is *not* styled.
Ive been googling a cause/fix for some time and i cant wrap my head around it.

I have tried copying some of Statamic's valet driver configs without much success as a www.conf file.
Also, ive seen some rewriting methods like

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
rewrite ^/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
```

also without success

I'd like to access home.test/app and have it load all required files and if possible to redirect home.test/app/ to home.test/app removing the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to be down to the use of `./` in the href of the link. You're telling the server "go grab me the file from the folder `/css/main.css` from my current folder location.

Assuming your folder structure is:

```
   /index.php
   /css/main.css
   /app/index.php
```

When you're on the home page, you're saying go and retrieve `home.test/css/main.css`. However, when in the app folder, you're telling the server to go and retrieve `home.test/app/css/main.css`, rather than `home.test/css/main.css`.

The quickest solution will be to change the link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">` (getting rid of the leading `.`). Otherwise you can use an absolute path.

Comment: well, its been a while, but if i remember correctly i was indeed trying to pull the css from the subfolder, not an abspath. i tried "file.css", "/file.css" and "./file.css" and they all disregard the folder they are in and pull from the root.
i just re-read my issue and it seems i made a mistake, i meant that "While in home.test/app/ it is NOT styled"